# org.eclipse.ui can't be resolved?

Tags: java, swt

Could you please tell me how to resolve that package import, I thought it is an element of SWT and I've already have SWT installed into Eclipse IDE. Why is it so bothersome? I guess I have to download some *.jar or *.zip files to add to my project as external library.

Please give me a solution. Thank you!

VipHaLong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `org.eclipse.ui` is definitely not part of SWT (or vice versa, but it requires SWT). If you are creating an RCP plugin (if not, you probably shouldn't be using `org.eclipse.ui`), you need to open `plugin.xml` file, "Dependencies" tab, and add `org.eclipse.ui` to "Required plugins".

Comment: I'm not sure but when I created SWT application (following some instruction found in the Internet), in detail, I right-clicked mouse on my project, select New -> Other, then select WindowBuilder -> SWT Designer -> Forms -> Composite. After that, the Eclipse included for me some imports, one of them is "org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit", but it can't be resolved. I explained this because I want to tell you that the unresolved import is not typed in myself, it's automatically added in by Eclipse. Thanks!

Comment: In that case you need `org.eclipse.ui.forms`, not `org.eclipse.ui`. Those are different plugins. I don't know if you can use Eclipse Forms outside RCP, but quite possibly not.

Comment: I suggest sticking with normal SWT for a start and not using Forms.

Comment: Do you mean 'not using Forms' is I should use console? I just want to see how SWT controls look, so I want to create a SWT application with a form and some SWT controls on it. Thanks.

Comment: No, use `SWT > Shell` or `SWT > Application Window` instead of `Forms > Composite`.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I don't really like the way Eclipse works, It should include all needed stuff for me once I choose Wizard as the way I start a new project. If it's so bothersome, I really like to code all myself, import all myself, ... In fact, I've never encountered the same problem when working with Netbeans. So disappointed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download SWT library. For 3.1.2 version of eclipse, SWT library is available at http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.1.2-200601181600/index.php Look for the section titled SWT Binary and Source.
2. Then follow this link:
   http://www.mkyong.com/swt/how-to-import-swt-library-into-eclipse-workspace/

follow it step by step and mostly you will get the solution. I was stuck with the same problem .